# Is there any solution for desired disconnecting in r shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, disconnect

I want to add a feature in my shiny app. My intention is that when the user does not click anywhere for 5 min in the website, the server will be disconnected.

Comment: This is typically controlled on the server-end, not within the app itself. Whichever server you are using (shinyapps, rstudio-server, posit-connect), look in their documentation for timeout settings. If you still can't find it, I suggest you go to the [Posit Community](https://community.rstudio.com/) for direct assistance.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `/etc/shiny-server` to the 'shiny-server.conf' file. In this file you can set the 'app_idle_timeout' parameter in seconds

this should help you

Comment: How can i find that file?

Comment: In my case the file is in the path ```/etc/shiny-server```